# Compile-time constants in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, compilation

I've been reading that arrays should have a size known at a compile time. Here is an example piece of code:

```
int temp = 5;
const int size = temp;
int array[size];
```

According to the author, the size is known  [at runtime and results in an error](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/61-arrays-part-i/).

However, I compiled and ran the code and there was no error.

Is the author right that in the above piece of code the size of the array is known at runtime? If he is, why was I able to compile and run the code?

In my opinion the size is known at compile-time. Is there something that I don't understand?

Edit. I used the g++ compiler and no extra options:
    g++ main.C -o main

Comment: Did you compile with GCC without `-pedantic`?

Comment: What compiler did you use? What command line arguments did you call it with? Usually compilers extend C++ with their own features. See for example: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html

Comment: No, I compiled it with g++. And yes, without *-pedantic*. But I'm not ansking about warnings - I'm asking about errors, so why does this option matter?

Comment: Something that the standard doesn't allow may still be allowed by an implementation / by an extension. This is the case here: arrays with a size known at runtime is not allowed by the standard, but GCC (g++) supports it.

Comment: g++ is part of GCC (the GNU Compiler Collection).

Comment: @user2738748 That option matters because it disables extensions. GCC supports variable-length arrays as an extension, hence the lack of errors.

Comment: @FelixBytow, TartanLiama, thank you for your explanation. I get it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`temp` is **not** known at compile time. You compiler **must** have a non-standard extension which permits variable length arrays.

A compiler would never assume that `temp` is immutable despite the fact that you clearly don't change it. (You might do one day which would then break your code horribly, and perhaps you could even conjure up a smart way of changing `temp`).

Answer (score 6):

The size is not known at compile time, even though it looks obvious. `temp` is not a compile time constant, which is used to initialize `size`, making it also not one.

It works for you because GCC allows variable length arrays as a non-standard language extension.

Comment: Could you explain to me why *temo* isn't a compile time constant?

Comment: temp is of type int, which is not compile-time-constant. What you would need is "static int const temp = 23;" or with C++ >= 11 you could also throw constexpr into the mix.

Comment: @FelixBytow, it may be a dumb and basic question, but I don't understand why int (the variable temp) isn't known at a compile time.  Could you explain that to me?

Comment: It is at the moment, but the compiler wouldn't bet its credibility on the fact.

Comment: The value (5) is a literal (const int), which is indeed known at compile time. The variable temp is just of type int and therefor may be modified at runtime. Any optimizations possibly turning temp into a compile-time-constant by detecting that it isn't changed, are completely implementation defined.

Comment: @FelixBytow, thank you. Now I get it.